# Problem with loading symbols during debugging in Visual Studio Code (VS Code)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, debugging, .net-core

So I have a pre built dotnet core site which I can't edit. Inside the site I have a CS project "Class Library" so that I can Customize the site with custom code.
When I build this "Class Library" project I get three files .dll, .pdb and .deps.json, which is fine.
After that if I launch this site and attach to it with Visual Studio it loads all thy symbols for my "Class Library" and I can debug it. But when I do the same thing with Visual Studio Code it sees the dll but does not load symbols for it saying: "Symbol loading is disabled by the include and exclude option". Obviously, I did not exclude it in launch.json
Does anyone know why is this happening?

My launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/BPMSoft.WebHost.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "suppressJITOptimizations": true,
            "requireExactSource": false,
            "justMyCode": false,
            "checkForDevCert": false,
            "symbolOptions": {
                "moduleFilter": {
                    "mode": "loadOnlyIncluded",
                    "includedModules": [ "*.dll" ],
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "suppressJITOptimizations": true,
            "requireExactSource": false,
            "justMyCode": false,
            "symbolOptions": {
                "moduleFilter": {
                    "mode": "loadOnlyIncluded",
                    "includedModules": [ "*.dll" ],
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My tasks.json:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/BPMSoft.Configuration/BPMSoft.Configuration.Dev.sln",
                "/target:BPMSoft_Configuration_Dev",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/BPMSoft.Configuration/BPMSoft.Configuration.Dev.sln",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "--project",
                "${workspaceFolder}/BPMSoft.Configuration/BPMSoft.Configuration.Dev.sln"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
    ]
}
```

When attaching to the application process with VS it says: Symbols loaded.

When attaching to the application process with VS Code it says: Symbols loading is disabled by the include and exclude option.

I tried different settings like: justMyCode, requireExactSource, suppressJITOptimizations and symbolOptions.moduleFilter.mode: "loadOnlyIncluded" with symbolOptions.moduleFilter.includedModules: [ "*.dll" ]
But none of that worked for me.

I am developing on Windows 10 if that matters.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images.